# Find and Replace string in a file C#

Tags: c#, file, replace, find

I want to find and take the keyword and then match from another keyword and then replace the values from the dictionary. You can see the content below which is in my text file. So, I need to find the $, and then I need to take the words which are within curly braces. For example, I need to take username,serviceName and serviceDescription.

So can you please tell me the easiest way to find this in a file and take the keywords as I described above.

```
Hi ${username},
Following services has reported  some issue:
${serviceName}: ${serviceDescription}
```

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Have a look at String.Format

Comment: Have you tried something out, yet? Also: What problem are you trying to solve? I have a feeling, this could be x-y.

Comment: How about using the "regular expression"? It should be easy, and fast.

Comment: Depending on the size of your dictionary and file, you could even just use [string.Replace(string,string)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.replace?view=netcore-3.1#System_String_Replace_System_String_System_String_)

Comment: Check my answer - I've used regex

Comment: This sounds like you're trying to write some sort of generic logging report and inputting dynamic variables.There maybe a better way of doing that but without more details of what your trying to achieve overall it's difficult to say.

Comment: @Amir : Thanks regular expression does the magic.

Comment: @abhijat_saxena: Thanks thats what i am looking for ...Regular expression does the magic.So I mark it as solved.

Comment: @abhijat_saxena : One more question i have regarding your solution like suppose we have something in dictionary but not in the file(log.txt) then dict[match.Groups[1].Value] will throw the exception.
Whats the best way to handle it

Comment: @abhijat_saxena : Suppose we have something in log.txt file but not in the dictionary key then we have a problem of exception.
```
var dict = new Dictionary<string, string>(StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase) {
                { "username", "alpha" }
           };
```
And we have two keywords in log.txt file that need to replaced username and servicename .
So in this scenario, I want to replace with matching only and ignore the other one.
So it will replace username as it is in the dictionary and it should leave the servicename as it is 
Do you have any idea how we can achieve this ?

Comment: found the solution of my question thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what I came up with :
I used C# Regular expressions and replaced the matches with the corresponding values in the dictionary

```
class Program
    {
        static readonly Regex re = new Regex(@"\$\{(\w+)\}", RegexOptions.Compiled);
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var dict = new Dictionary<string, string>(StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase) {
                { "username", "alpha" },
                { "serviceName", "azure service" },
                { "serviceDescription", "azure service has stopped" }
           };

            var log = File.ReadAllText("log.txt");

            string output = re.Replace(log, match => dict[match.Groups[1].Value]);
        }
    }
```

Your output would look something like this

```
Hi alpha,
Following services has reported  some issue:
azure service: azure service has stopped
```

Comment: Thank you very much thats what i am looking for.